# Why the Google login is not progressing when wrapping a web development project in React Native to create a mobile app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/in0fF.png)

Can you explain why the Google login is not progressing when wrapping a web development project in React Native to create a mobile app? I'd like to understand the reason behind this issue. I see that the loading screen keeps appearing without progressing to the next step.

The transition works fine on the web, but it seems to encounter issues when wrapped in React Native. Is it a problem with React Native itself, or is there an issue specifically with the Google login?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.